# How can I handle unexpected error in my expressjs app to avoid downtime?

Tags: node.js, express, exception

How can I handle unexpected errors in my Express app to avoid downtime?

My first thought was to use try/catch statements to handle unexpected error, but that only works with synchronous code. I found that one possible option was to use Node.js's 'Domain Module', however, it turns out, that it is deprecated, and will remain deprecated.

Currently I am handling errors, by using middle-ware that is provided by the express generator. I am also using a process monitoring program called forever. Is the process-monitoring and Express's middle-ware enough to for successful unexpected error handling, or are there other options that I should be considering?

Answer (score 1):

To answer you bluntly, you cannot handle your unexpected errors. This is not to say you can not handle errors, obviously you can, should and must. What I am saying is if an error is handled, then the program expected it, and it is not unexpected, if the program did not expect it then it is unexpected, so essentially if you do handle the unexpected errors, your not handling unexpected errors, your just handling errors.

As developers it is our job to thoroughly element unexpected errors as best we can, though none of us will ever succeed completely. Through devotion, and rigorous effort, a level can be achieved where the unexpected errors in your code that do occur are very minimal, and the situation is tolerable, at least to a certain degree. Error handling is a process that will often continue long after a beta version release, and even long after the first real production release. As data is collected, in a way I will soon talk about, bugs/errors are found and eliminated through versioning & patching, techniques designed to continue increasing the integrity of software even long after it has been released.

As you should already understand, there is not one single fix that will take care of all your unexpected errors. You as a developer should rid your app of all programmatic errors before production, and handle operational errors as best you can, which means you should understand what a Programmatic error, and operational error is.

- #1. Programmatic-Errors: errors and/or bugs within the code itself.
- #2. Operational-Errors - "Errors that occur in areas that are outside of the control of the programmer. Errors caused be the client, by the network, by the V8-Engine(this can be Programmatic too though).

There is no clear cut way to define every error as either operational or programmatic, and grey areas do exist. There are ways of looking at the errors in question that can help make a definitive determination. If you look at your code and figure that you couldn't solve the error, by writing different code, or more code, its likely not a programmatic error. If your getting errors trying to connect to a particular host, and your connecting everywhere else just fine, it is likely operational. Operational errors occur, even when the code of the application is written flawlessly, just make sure your correct in your determination of your codes integrity.

Here is a couple examples:
OPERATIONAL ERRORS

1. Socket Drops
2. Request timeout
3. Failed to authenticate client credentials
4. Any errors caused by legality issues

Here is a couple examples:
PROGRAMMATIC ERRORS

1. Invalid type-of variable passed into a function
2. Incorrect/Invalid Syntax
3. Failed to authenticate client credentials
4. Name clashing

As I already pointed out, the purpose of understanding these two error types, is so you as a developer can eliminate all the errors, that you are not only responsible for eliminating, but you need to eliminate in order to have a half decent working application. In the world of Node.js Application Development, this is the part that separates The Hero from the Zero, the Women from the girls, Glorious Chihuahuas from Sasquatch (Okay I am bias towards chihuahuas) You get the Idea.

This is really not a Question or Topic that can be answered in a one liner, mainly because, you can't just handle all unexpected errors with some 3rd party NPM API, but also because learning, and knowing what to do is not a matter of learning more JavaScript syntax, but instead learning a paradigm that every developer who wants to build solid, well built Node.js applications needs to know.

I know some of you are talking smack right now, thinking you have the answer and it is so simple. Well its not. Those of you who are using, the event listener that catches uncaught/unexpected errors are not putting great applications into production, if any applications. I sure hope any company you work for doesn't let you put out code that uses it. For those who don't know what I am talking about it bellow this text block. FYI, its already been suggested on this page, which blows me away.

```
  //Catch uncaught exceptions
    process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
      // handle the error safely
      console.log(err);
    });
```

**ABOVE IS THE PERFECT EXAMPLE OF WHAT NOT TO DO!!!!!!**

If an error occurs unexpectedly the right thing to do is throw it as an Error Object. Not doing this threatens the integrity of your entire application. Remember you will be away from your server when clients have to deal with the results of your failure to do what you were told was the right thing to do. Using the above code snippet threatens the Security of your server. This includes the information needed to access your server, your pem keys, your passwords, all your databases and databases data, and worst of all any client info you store including any credit cards and passwords you keep (make sure you Blow-fish that kind of stuff). Every thing is put at risk the minute you launch an app that handles unexpected errors this way.

possible issues include:

1. Memory references, that are used and passed around on the V-8 c++ level, can potentially get majorly screwed up. This could result in massive memory leaks. You may end up without the necessary memory to fulfill requests, or do anything for that matter. Memory leaks are a major topic right now in the node community, as developers are having a heck of a time debugging them.
2. Some transactions can get left open, especially during memory leaks, and the wrong request and data can get sent to the wrong users. Random people can wind up getting sent the session ID's of other people. This is something hackers will quickly take advantage of, especially if there's any finances involved.

There are actually several more, and memory leaking is a big problem despite making it worse to try to make another problem better. You can make both better, you as a developer just need to have integrity, thus your app will have integrity.

The reason that event even occurs is for logging and monitoring. It is actually implemented by default in each node instance ran, and is part of how Error objects manage to inform you of, and about, unexpected errors. Below is the correct way to use it.

```
process.on('uncaughtExceptionMonitor', (err, origin) => {
  MyMonitoringTool.logSync(err, origin);
  
  // if needed pass the error to a function that will throw it...
});
```

The above is an example from the Node.js website, where you can read further about error handling, and unexpected errors.

[Node.js Official Error Handling Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexceptionmonitor)

Lastly we talking about Error monitors. For small applications, error monitors maybe all you need in order to do a satisfactory job. The only way to know if you have done enough for errors & unexpected errors to go production, is to get to the point where you feel you have error handling for all your operational errors, and your programmatic errors have all been corrected. Then you need a logging system that logs your errors. You can build your own logging system or purchase one for a regular fee. You will need a monitor, again you could technically build one, and for most stuff I would suggest trying, but for this I would pay a very small monthly fee, and it will restart your application if it crashes due to unexpected errors.

The answers above were really bad, but this has some good stuff in it. I did get help from the Node site that I liked to above. I also got help from here, a resource I have referenced time and time again, you should too.[Handling Unexpected errors in Node Applications](https://www.joyent.com/node-js/production/design/errors#5-if-you-pass-a-lower-level-error-to-your-caller-consider-wrapping-it-instead)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend pm2 over forever as it has several great features. We use it in our production website and it works great. Enable logging to track your exceptions.

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

PM2 allows you to manage logs easily. You can display all application logs in real-time, flush them, and reload them. There are also different ways to configure how PM2 will handle your logs (separated in different files, merged, with timestamp...) without modifying anything in your code.

Comment: So I should use 'pm2' instead npm 'forever'.

Comment: I would definitely use pm2. It is much more powerful as I explained in the first sentence of my answer.

Answer (score -2):

I have handled this in my application by listing to uncaught error on process in my "index.js".

```
    //Catch uncaught exceptions
    process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
      // handle the error safely
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use try-catch using a combination of generators and promises. - https://gist.github.com/swarajgiri/16202e32aa4d80d45c62

On catching an error, pass it to an error handler, in your `server/app.js`.

```
// errors handler. 
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    if (! err) {
        return next();
    }

    res.status(500);
    res.send('500: Internal server error');
});
```

You will still need to have either `forever` or `pm2` manage it.

Comment: ```
    res.status(500);
    res.send('500: Internal server error');
```
now it is combined in one function: res.sendStatus(500) the description will be added automatically.